# cd command doesn't work with Pycharm/IdeaVim

Tags: pycharm

I'm using PyCharm with IdeaVim, and I have a little issue. I'm trying to execute the following command in Vim:

```
:! cd ./Desktop
```

However, I got the following error, and I don't know why :

```
Cannot run program "cd": error=2, No such file or directory.
```

I'd like to execute that kind of command in PyCharm. How could I fix this little issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IdeaVim != Vim.

Looking at [the code](https://github.com/JetBrains/ideavim/blob/master/src/com/maddyhome/idea/vim/group/ProcessGroup.java#L201), it uses [Runtime.exec()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String)) to run commands, which doesn't use a shell. So, `:!cd` is meaningless here.

Comment: I have a similar problem with `gvim` (`/bin/bash: line 0: cd: Desktop: No such file or directory`). Is there a way to fix it in both situation?

Comment: @DavidHilbert that is a different problem. You should be doing `cd ~/Desktop`. But if you want to change directories in Vim proper, use [`:cd` instead of `:!cd`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/editing.txt.html#%3Acd).

Comment: Thanks for that! Do you know if there exists  a solution for the question.

Comment: @DavidHilbert file a feature request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/VIM

Comment: I know you are likely a good user of Vim. Do you use `Vundle` to install a plugin?

Comment: @DavidHilbert I started with pathogen and now I use vim-plug: https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug.

Comment: Is there a reason why you use vim-plug instead of another, Vundle for instance?

Comment: @DavidHilbert just the awkward initialisation of Vundle (turn off `filetype`, manually add to `rtp`). And `vim-plug` does all that I need it to.